# remove lines with sed that follow a particular line

Tags: sed

I am trying to remove *all* (including new lines) content with sed that comes after the following text in a file (/etc/sudoers):

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -e '\|\#includedir /etc/sudoers\.d|q' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have asked a lot sooner. Been beating my head against the wall on this one.